# File location after push

Tags: git

I am new at git. I am using Egit. What I have done were:
Created a repository in X:\coy_wcag(Mapping drive) by using command line

```
git init
```

After that, I clone this project by using **Import->Git->project from Git->Clone**. A project has successfully created in my local workspace. Then I have added a file called **kkkk.html**, **commit** and **push/push to upstream** it to branch. However, when I go to X:\coy_wcag, the **kkkk.html** doesn't exist. I have checked the remotes setting is using 'origin' and set to be file:///X:\coy_wcag already.

In order to check if the commit and push action success or not, I clone it again but in other directory, the **kkkk.html** appears!!!

I don't know why I cannot find the file in x:\coy_wcag please help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When working with a remote repository you should work on a `bare` repository. It is highly discouraged to push to a non-bare repository.

You initialise a `bare` repository by using `git init --bare`.

To understand the difference to a usual repository you can take a look at [this article](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/shared-repositories-should-be-bare-repositories/). Simply said, a `bare` repository doesn't contain the files directly but the content of the `.git` folder. It only tracks your changes, you are not supposed to work in a bare repository.

---

**USING THE FOLLOWING SOLUTION IS HIGHLY DISCURAGED! INSTEAD ALWAYS TRY TO USE A BARE REPOSITORY!**

If you still want to update the work tree of the remote repository you can follow this steps:

```
# Go into the remote repository
git config --local receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
git config --local core.worktree "$(pwd)"
```

Now place the following script into a `.git/hooks/post-receive` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This hook will update the working tree to match the latest pushed commit

git checkout -f
```

After you have done this the remote repository will update it's work tree every time it recieves a push.

#### IMPORTANT

This `post-receive` hook will override **any** changes which are currently in the work tree of the remote repository. So keep this in mind!

Comment: yes. I know I should use --bare even though I don't quite understand how it works. But what my situation is, someone need to directly change the file in remote. So what I want to do is, I can fetch changes from remote before I do some editing. This is strange but cannot be avoid since my company didn't use git for version control and I don't want to break their current file structure.

Comment: @PandaYang I'm not sure I understand. Why can't you use a bare repository?

Comment: because if use --bare, then my PM cannot directly edit the files in Remote/Repository. I need to let him can directly edit the files in shared drive, and keep the most updated copy in my local workspace.

Comment: @PandaYang You never should directly edit the files in a remote repository. Can't you just create a clone for him/them too?

Comment: I know that, but the truth is, I have to let him/them do this. Create a clone for him/them is too difficult for him/them and also need to change current file structure, I think I won't be allow to do this. so sad.

Comment: @PandaYang I've expanded my answer with a solution to your issue. Keep in mind that doing it this way is highly discuraged.

Answer (score 0):

Next time after you push, go to the upstream folder an pull the changes

```
git fetch
git pull
```

Git only push a reference to the changes, it won't change the files automatically

Comment: While you are correct, you should always use a `bare` repository as a remote; take a look at my answer.